# How to know the which functionality or widget takes more memory in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing memory issue in my flutter applications. I need to identity the exact widget or functionality caused the memory issue or taking too much memory. I run it in profile mode but not able to find the exact thing that causes the memory issue. I need to optimize my app .

So any ways to identify the exact causes?

Comment: you may check this [Using the Memory view](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/memory#memory-view-guide)

Comment: I tried.  it gives an overall idea not the widgets caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

try to make flutter app without using setState and use notifiers to update widgets will speed up your app performance

Comment: we are not using setState.But when some pages are open app is closed due to memory issue